# Overridden Font property in custom usercontrol not displaying in designer file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom user control and have overridden its Font property.

When I drop a copy of my usercontrol onto a form, I can set the Font property just fine, but I don't see the value I set for 'Font' showing up in my form's designer file.  When I compile/run my app, the value I entered is lost.

Note that I also want to override the Text property and couldn't see the set value for this in the designer file either -- until I found an answer on here to help do that (I needed to set the  the 'DesignerSerializationVisibility' and 'EditorBrowsable' attributes).  I've tried doing the same for Font but to no avail.  Any ideas?

```
    private Font _Font = UserControl.DefaultFont;

    [Description("Sets the font of the button caption"),,
     Browsable(true),
     Bindable(true),
     EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
     DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get { return _Font; }
        set
        {
            _Font = value;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you not just use `base.Font`? What's the point of having two instances?

Comment: Noticed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font.aspx) in documentation as well: " *Notes to Inheritors
When overriding the Font property in a derived class, use the base class's Font property to extend the base implementation. Otherwise, you must provide all the implementation. You are not required to override both the get and set accessors of the Font property; you can override only one if needed.* "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
public UserControl1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  base.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;
}

[Description("Sets the font of the button caption")]
public override Font Font
{
  get { return _Font; }
  set { _Font = base.Font = value; }
}
```

Comment: That does get the value into the designer file, but setting the base Font property throws all of the sizing of the children controls on my user control out of whack.  If I increase the font size, for instance, the buttons I have on the user control will grow.

Comment: @Mike R. Updated answer: turn AutoScaleMode = Font (default) to None.