# UserControl Shows Property in Visual Studio Designer, But Property Is Not Changed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

So today, I decided to create a custom TextButton control in C# using Visual Studio 2012.  I quite like the design I've made, simple as it may be.  However, when I decided I would move my completed component into a form using the Visual Studio Designer, I ran into a snag.  Although the Text property shows up in the properties list, the property is not not actually being changed in the MainWindow.Designer.cs file.  Below is the code that defines the property:

```
[Category("Appearance")]
[Description("The text displayed by the control.")] 
[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        return Button.Text;
    } 
    set
    {
        Button.Text = value;
    }
}
```

And here is the code that my MainWindow.Designer.cs file is creating in the InitializeComponent method:

```
this.Open = new UI.Controls.TextButton();
this.Open.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 3);
this.Open.Name = "Open";
this.Open.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 28);
this.Open.TabIndex = 4;
this.Open.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.OpenButton_Click);
```

Comment: Is this an UserControl or a Custom Control, in short are you inheriting from Button.

Comment: It is a UserControl with a System.Windows.Forms.Button docked in the middle to take over the entire view of the control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are overriding the `UserControl's` `Text` Property. If you name your property another name besides `Text` such as `myText` it will work. In order to fix the problem you have using `Text` try adding the [`DesignerSerializationVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute.aspx) Attribute to your Property, that should take care of it.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
```

Comment: The designer still does not add the overwritten property to MyControl.Designer.cs file. I change the value using Properties windows, the designer shows it, but after rebuilt or close/open the [designe] it is gone.

Comment: It seem you have to add base.Text = value;. It is working now. From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915933/overridden-font-property-in-custom-usercontrol-not-displaying-in-designer-file