# .NET Override Form Text Property

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, inheritance

I have a form called `MyForm` that inherits from `Windows.Forms.Form`. On this form I have a `TextBox` called `_msgBox`. Now, when I set the `Text` property on `MyForm`  I actually want to set `_msgBox`'s `Text` property. I wrote a simple property to do this:

```
Public Overloads Property Text As String
    Get
        Return _msgBox.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _msgBox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

However, this didn't work. So, I used my Google-fu and was able to find [this forum post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/c-sharp-user-control-text-property-override), at which point I changed my code to:

```
<Browsable(True)>
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
<Bindable(True)>
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
Public Overloads Property Text As String
    Get
        Return _msgBox.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _msgBox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This still didn't fix the problem, so I check here on SO and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915933/overridden-font-property-in-custom-usercontrol-not-displaying-in-designer-file), which suggested that I also needed to set the base property too. I did so, and my code now looks like this:

```
<Browsable(True)>
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
<Bindable(True)> 
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
Public Overloads Property Text As String
    Get
        Return _msgBox.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        MyBase.Text = value
        _msgBox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But I'm still not seeing this property get set. When I call `MyForm.Text`, the base `Text` property is set but my inner property remains unset. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you want to override, why are you using the `Overloads` keyword instead of the `Overrides` keyword?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Auto-complete?

Comment: @VisualVincent I also voted to close it. I didn't notice because I'm not used to VB.NET having an `overloads` keyword

Comment: Actually, there is a bit more to the issue than that because, even if you override instead of overloading, the code as it is would still throw a `NullReferenceException`, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney This is true, and if that's enough of an issue then you could leave it. I would've fixed that myself already except this code was never actually hit ;)

Comment: I retracted my vote again due to what jmcilhinney said. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some testing and this works:

```
Public Overrides Property Text As String
    Get
        Return If(TextBox1 Is Nothing, MyBase.Text, TextBox1.Text)
    End Get
    Set
        MyBase.Text = Value
        TextBox1.Text = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Note that, in the getter, it tests to see whether the `TextBox` exists and uses it only if it does, otherwise it uses the form.  I started with this:

```
Return TextBox1.Text
```

and I was getting a `NullReferenceException` thrown, presumably because the `Text` property value was being used before the `TextBox` was created.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than what you're trying. Simply change the TextBox's text via the Form's TextChanged event:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.TextChanged
        TextBox1.Text = Me.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Text = "My New Text"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Try this on a Form, and when the form loads, the TextBox will have the same text as the Form.